# javascript validate input with blur can't get autocompletion results

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-maps-api-3, onblur

http://jsfiddle.net/ca11111/rYAqS/

My problem is I want to validate an input that uses googlemaps autocomplete and then geocode it, but blur event is triggered too early

see the jsfiddle, type "Par", then select Paris, france, and you don't get the geocode of Paris but of Par, see the code

good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
   //var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
   validateStart();
});
```

Comment: yes thanks seems to work, but in general autocompletions, How do you validate the input and make sure you get the autocompleted word and not just the letters typed?

Comment: Also don't need to geocode anymore since already done in autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location

Comment: "blur" happens when the element loses focus. That happens when you tab out of it or click on the autocomplete. If the autocomplete changes the input field, that will happen after it's blurred. You may need to catch the onchange event and test for focus.

Comment: Tried onchange, it's not better, could you show me how you would do that?

Comment: No: you're right, it won't work. But you can delay the test to allow the autocomplete to do its stuff. `<input type="text" id="start" onblur="setTimeout(validateStart,50);"/>` That might be classed as a hack, though.